# Calling solr api using custom apis in lafresco

Tags: alfresco, solrj, alfresco-share, solr4, alfresco-webscripts

I want to call this api into my web project or in my java backed api

***> http://localhost:8080/share/proxy/alfresco/slingshot/node/search?q=cm:name:*%20AND%20TYPE:%22vmr:unindexed%22%20AND%20PATH:%22%20/app:company_home//*%22&lang=fts-alfresco&store=workspace://SpacesStore&maxResults=1000&alf_ticket=TICKET_b40bdd7327096633838cacfa916c794976461fda***

1.when i am calling url using poster it's giving 401 unauthorized.
2.After login as a admin when i am calling then it's working fine untill session has expired.

After Spent some hour found that there is  Alfresco-csrf ticket is used by solr4 to authenticate

Ques- 1.Can anyone tell me how to generate Alfresco-csrf ticket and pass along with request?
2.If that is not possible can any one tell me how can i use solr api's directly as alfresco is using?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can generate an Alfresco Ticket with an url like this:
http://localhost:8383/alfresco/service/api/login?u=your-user&pw=your-password

You must change "localhost:8383" with the url of your alfresco, "your-user" with the appropiate user, and "your-password" with a valid password in Alfresco.

Regards,

Comment: Thanks mr @calvo but that api is useful to generate alf_ticket not for csrf token and even i am not able to prevent the seesion also .